# How is it that $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} \Phi(x)\Delta v(x) dx = v(0)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We know that $\Phi(x):=\frac{1}{(n-2)\omega_n|x|^{n-2}}$ for $n\ge3$ is the fundamental solution for the Laplace's equation. Given that $v\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$ has compact support, how is it that we can verify the integral?

$$\int_{\mathbb{R^{n}}} \Phi(x) \Delta v(x) dx = v(0) $$

For reference, I am reading/studying *Partial Differential Equations* (2nd Ed) by Lawrence Evans.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of distributional derivatives and since $-\Delta\Phi = \delta_0$ in the sense of distributions,
$$
\int \Phi(x)\,\Delta v(x)\,\mathrm d x = \langle \Delta\Phi, v\rangle = -\langle \delta_0, v\rangle = -v(0).
$$
Does it answer your question or was your question about why $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace equation?

Comment: From where does the relation $\int \Phi(x) \Delta v(x) dx = \left< \Delta\Phi(x), v(x) \right>$ come? I don't think I've ever seen that.

Comment: If $\Phi$ was a nice function, this is just integration by parts ... in this case since it is not, it follows from the definition of distributional derivative: $\langle \partial_{k}f,\varphi\rangle = -\langle f,\partial_{k}\varphi\rangle$
$$
\int \Phi(x)\,\Delta v(x)\,\mathrm d x = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle \Phi,\partial_k^2v\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle - \partial_k \Phi,\partial_kv\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle \partial_k^2 \Phi,v\rangle = \langle \Delta \Phi,v\rangle
$$